# В чём отличие npm install --save-dev от --save

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

В чем заключается отличие команд `--save-dev` и `--save` при установке пакета через `npm`?

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/170263

https://toster.ru/answer?answer_id=559717#comments_list_559717

Comment: В разные секции зависимостей package.json попадет ваш пакет (в обычные или дивелопперские)

Answer (score 20):

**-S, --save:** Пакет будет отображается в ваших dependencies

**-D, --save-dev:** пакет будет отображаться в ваших devDependencies

Для более подробной информации смотрите [npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Answer (score 16):

В версии npm 6.5 можно не писать `-save` или `-s` , npm сам добавит установленный пакет вам в "dependencies": { }.

Из документации https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install :

`-P`, `--save-prod`: опять же сохранит в "dependencies": { }. Это ваш код для продакшена, он будет включен в ваш конечный продукт. Добавляйте сюда только те библиотеки, которые будут использованы при работе вашего конечного продукта (вэб страницы например).

`-D`, `--save-dev`: сохранит пакет в "devDependencies": { }. Это пакеты, которые вы используете в процессе девелопмента, препроцессоры LESS, SASS, валидаторы кода, JShint Slint, препроцессоры JS: Babel. Эти пакеты не будут включены в конечный продукт.

`-O`, `--save-optional`: пакет будет добавлен в "optionalDependencies": { }. эти пакеты могут быть использованы в работе, но если они будут недоступны или произойдет ошибка при их установке, то npm просто пропустит их и продолжит работу.

`--no-save`: Запрещает сохранять пакет в package.json.

+Дополнительные флаги:

`-E`, `--save-exact`: сохранит версию пакета точно, как указано.

`-B`, `--save-bundle`: сохранит пакет в "bundleDependencies": { }.

Comment: А что, если мы код для продакшина собираем и запихиваем в бандл, который собственно и подгружаем, как пример SPA на React или Vue. Получается нам все равно, в dependencies или в DevDependencies запихивать модули?

Answer (score 11):

Если указывать флаг ***--save*** то при установке пакета, его имя и версия пропишутся в файле **package.json** в разделе **dependencies**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если установить с флагом ***--save-dev***, то имя и версия попадут в раздел **devDependencies**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -4):

Если правильно помню, то когда добавляешь `-dev` , то помимо пакета ставится все, от чего он зависим.

Например:

```
bower install jqueryvalidation --save-dev
```

Поставит jqueryvalidation и jquery. т.к. как зависим от нее. если указать без -dev, то jquery поставлена не будет.

Comment: Нет, это не так. См. ответ @stas0k