# Установка Bootstrap через NPM

Tags: bootstrap, npm

Пытаюсь установить Bootstrap через NPM и вроде как получается, но я испытываю полное непонимание того, что я делаю. Например, нужно ли прописывать `--save` для установки Bootstrap и для чего автоматически создается `package-lock.json`? Если не сложно, расскажите пожалуйста свой процесс установки.

```
npm install jquery@3.3.1 --save
npm install popper.js@^1.14.3 --save
npm install bootstrap@4.1.1 --save
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549343/%D0%92-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-npm-install-save-dev-%D0%BE%D1%82-save

Answer (score 1):

1. Либо `--save` либо `-S` прописывать надо для того, что бы при компиляций у тебя в билде проекта подтянулась эта зависимость. Если тебе какая та зависимость нужна только на время разработки, а в релизе она не нужна, то пишешь либо `--save-dev`, либо `-D`.

   2. `package-lock.json` вообще забудь о нем, он создается для компа, в нем просто намного больше инфы, которую можно использовать, а сам работай c `package.json`